# Why does jQuery do this in its constructor function implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If we look at the latest jQuery source at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js we see the following:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```

My understanding of the new keyword in Javascript is essentially JavaScript passes the function an empty object `{}` and the function sets stuff on it via `this.blah`.

Also from my understanding `new` differs from `.call`/`.apply` etc.. in that the return object also has the prototype set to that of the function. So the return value should have a prototype that the same as `jQuery.prototype.init.prototype` (or `jQuery.fn.init.prototype`). However from what I see its prototype is set to `jQuery.prototype` thus all the commands available to work on the set.

Why is this? What am I missing in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look deeper into [jQuery's code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js), you'll notice this line:

```
// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

This is for readability/structure purposes so the constructor can have its own method.

There's no real "magic" being done here, just standard JavaScript, albeit in a slightly less commonly used way, perhaps. It's useful in jQuery's case since the library is pretty lengthy and this adds good structure/readability to it.

Answer (score 0):

In that source file, search for the string "Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation" :-)

The code sets the `prototype` reference of `jQuery.fn.init` to `jQuery.prototype` (which is the same as `jQuery.fn` I think).