# Why does the jQuery constructor map to jQuery.fn.init?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `jQuery` constructor sort of maps its functionality to another constructor, `jQuery.fn.init`:

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

I'm wondering why.

[This question is very similar, but even the answerer admits they didn't really answer the question as to *why*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754560/help-understanding-jquerys-jquery-fn-init-why-is-init-in-fn)

[This question is still unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782973/why-is-the-init-function-in-jquery-prototype-and-not-in-jquerys-closure?rq=1)

**Is this just for organizational purposes?** Rather than putting the init function inside the jQuery constructor definition, maybe the authors wanted to package it.

**Is there any reason to have the `.init()` method on the prototype?**  I don't think anyone ever uses `$('.something')...init()...`

**[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782973/why-is-the-init-function-in-jquery-prototype-and-not-in-jquerys-closure?rq=1) shows that its not necessary to have `.init` on the prototype.**

And I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477370/why-does-jquery-do-this-in-its-constructor-function-implementation) in which Dan Herbert's answer suggests that it is simply for structure/readability purposes.

In conclusion, **can I confirm that this constructor/prototype mapping funny-business is kind of unnecessary?**  It seems to me that the `jQuery.fn.init` functionality *could* go:

- Anywhere in the closure
- On the `jQuery` object (`jQuery.init` vs `jQuery.fn.init`)
- Or, what makes most sense to me: directly inside the `jQuery` function/constructor definition, replacing `new jQuery.fn.init` and avoiding the `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn` mapping.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143590/difference-of-the-value-prototype-and-property) - yes, `init` is a bit unncessary but they wanted to make the actual constructor public.

Comment: Now that [Why is the init function in jQuery.prototype and not in jQuery's closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782973/why-is-the-init-function-in-jquery-prototype-and-not-in-jquerys-closure) has an answer it's a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The jQuery constructor sort of maps its functionality to another
>   constructor

The fact is that `jQuery` is not really a constructor function and shouldn't be seen as one either. By definition, a constructor's responsability is to initialize instance properties, which is not really the case with `jQuery`. Also, calling `new jQuery()` would be non-sense. **`jQuery` is a factory function for creating `jQuery.fn.init` instances, nothing more**.

Now, perhaps you are wondering why they simply didin't use `jQuery` as a real constructor?

Well because they did not want a constructor that we call with `new` all the time, they wanted a factory function. That's fine with me, however where I tend to disagree is that their pattern is **very cryptic and doesn't quite reflect the intention**.

It would have been far better in my opinion to chose better names:

```
function jQuery(selector, context) {
    return new jQuery.Set(selector, context);
}

jQuery.Set = function (selector, context) {
    //constructor logic
};

//allows syntaxic sugar
jQuery.fn = jQuery.Set.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery.Set,
    //methods
};
```

I've pretty much only remapped `jQuery.fn.init` to `jQuery.Set` and it suddenly all makes more sense to me. When looking at the code above, it's easy to see that:

1. `jQuery` is a factory function for creating `jQuery.Set` objects.
2. `jQuery.fn` exists only as a syntaxic sugar, instead of having to write `jQuery.Set.prototype` all the time to modify the prototype.

Now, in the source we also see that they do the following, which is kinda non-sense since `jQuery` is not the real constructor, it's `jQuery.prototype.init` and since we aren't creating `jQuery` instances, setting `jQuery.prototype` seems useless:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
      constructor: jQuery
```

One of the reasons behind this is certainly that they want to accomodate people that might modify `jQuery.prototype` instead of `jQuery.fn`.

However another valid reason is that they perhaps wanted `somejQueryObj instanceof jQuery` to returns true, while it normally wouldn't. If you take the pattern above (with jQuery.Set) you will notice that:

```
jQuery() instanceof jQuery; //false
jQuery() instanceof jQuery.Set; //true
```

However if we set the `prototype` of `jQuery` to `jQuery.Set.prototype`, let's see what happens.

```
jQuery.prototype = jQuery.Set.prototype;
jQuery() instanceof jQuery; //true!
```

**It's not easy to understand eveything that led to those design decisions and perhaps I am missing important points, but to me it seems their design is overcomplicated.**

Comment: Looks good to me, not missing really important points.

Answer (score -1):

It allows you the chain the constructor. Kind of...

So instead of

```
$('.someClass').hide();
$('.someOtherClass').hide();
```

You can do

```
$('.someClass').hide().init.call($.fn, '.someOtherClass').hide();
```

This works, but it's also a joke.

Comment: Possibly yes, but you would never want to apply the `init` function on the `$.fn` prototype object!

Comment: Of course not, but can you think of any other application?

Comment: Check my answer on the [not any more unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782973/why-is-the-init-function-in-jquery-prototype-and-not-in-jquerys-closure).